# Settimeout function with a big interval eats a lot of CPU power

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu, settimeout

I have to refresh a page every 30 minutes and I use settimeout function to accopmplish this. So, my interval is 1800000. With such an interval I face to a performance problem. It seems that settimeout is quite greedy function. Is there a better solution to accopmplish my task?

Comment: Are you sure that the performance problem is created by `setTimeout`? Have you used a profiler?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of `setTimeout` performance issues.

If a large timeout was an issue, then you could just do something like this to still check if 30 minutes has expired, but reduce the timeout duration i.e. check every minute if 30 minutes has passed:

```
var oneMinute = 60000;
var expired = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 30*oneMinute);
var checkExpired = function(){
 if( new Date() < expired) {setTimeout(checkExpired, oneMinute); }
 else { reloadPage();}
});
setTimeout(checkExpired, oneMinute);
```

Comment: You could also use `setInterval` instead if you are going to use this method to poll every X minutes.